# Help with calculating a complicated integral

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, functions, programming, numerical-integration

**Edit: The question is solved** : )) Thank you for your attention !

I am sorry for mass questions, but the question bothers me a lot. So I would like to ask this question here.

This problem arises when I tried to compute the valua of [Asian call otions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_option) using the inverse Laplace transform method.  *The method I use here is very new since it computes the Asian call options in very new way !* george2079 asked me  whether the theoretical part of the"new method" has a problem. I would like to confirm that: two of us have checked the theoretial part more than 10 times and we confirm that it is correct.

Let $r=\mu = 0.15;
\sigma = 0.20;
T = 1;
S_0 = 100;
K = 95;$

Let $\nu:=\frac{2\mu}{\sigma^2}-1$

and  $\boxed{\eta \equiv\eta(\alpha)}:=-\frac{\nu}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\nu^2+\frac{8\alpha}{\sigma^2}}$.

Define $F$ as follows:
$$ 
F(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{\Gamma(\eta+2\mu/\sigma^2)}{\Gamma(2\eta +2\mu/\sigma^2)} \int_K^{\infty}\left(\frac{2S_0}{y\sigma^2}\right)^{\eta}M(\eta, 2\eta+\frac{2\mu}{\sigma^2}, -\frac{2S_0}{y\sigma^2}) \, dy
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function
and $M$ is the a confluent hypergeometric function

($M$ is the `Hypergeometric1F1` function in *Mathematica*).

I am trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of $F(\alpha)$ numerically.

$$V(t)=\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma- iz}^{\gamma +iz} e^{t\alpha}F(\alpha)d \alpha $$
at $t=1$.

Note that if we let $b=\left(\frac{2S_0}{\sigma^2}\right)$, and $z=b/y$
then we have
$$ 
F(\alpha)=\frac{1}{\alpha} \left(\frac{2S_0}{\sigma^2}\right)\frac{\Gamma(\eta+2\mu/\sigma^2)}{\Gamma(2\eta +2\mu/\sigma^2)} \int_0^{\frac{b}{K}}z^{\eta-2}M(\eta, 2\eta+\frac{2\mu}{\sigma^2}, -z) \, dz
$$

***So using the ideas suggested by Dr. Hintze and  I_Mariusz and [the package written by Prof Valko](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4738/)***, I write a *Mathematica* program to compute it. Please see the *Mathematica* code here

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(*The program used to find the Inverse Laplace transform numerically*)

GWR[F_, t_, M_: 32, precin_: 0] := 
  Module[
  {M1, G0, Gm, Gp, best, expr, τ = Log[2]/t, Fi, broken, prec},
  If[precin <= 0, prec = 21 M/10, prec = precin];
  If[prec <= $MachinePrecision, prec = $MachinePrecision];
  broken = False;
  If[Precision[τ] < prec, τ = SetPrecision[τ, prec]];
  Do[Fi[i] = N[F[i τ], prec], {i, 1, 2 M}];
  M1 = M;
  Do[
     G0[n - 1] = τ (2 n)!/(n! (n - 1)!) Sum[
              Binomial[n, i] (-1)^i  Fi[n + i], {i, 0, n}];
     If[Not[NumberQ[G0[n - 1]]], M1 = n - 1; G0[n - 1] =.; 
Break[]];
     , {n, 1, M}];
  Do[Gm[n] = 0, {n, 0, M1}];
  best = G0[M1 - 1];

  Do[
     Do[
        expr = G0[n + 1] - G0[n];

If[Or[Not[NumberQ[expr]], expr == 0], broken = True; Break[]];
        expr = Gm[n + 1] + (k + 1)/expr;
        Gp[n] = expr;
        If[OddQ[k],
           If[n == M1 - 2 - k, best = expr]
           ];
        , {n, M1 - 2 - k, 0, -1}];
     If[broken, Break[]];
     Do[Gm[n] = G0[n]; G0[n] = Gp[n], {n, 0, M1 - k}];
     , {k, 0, M1 - 2}];
  best
  ]

(*Model parameters*)
mu = 0.15;
sigma = 0.20;
S0 = 100;
K = 95;
T = 1;

 eq = z^(nu - 2)*Hypergeometric1F1[nu, 2*nu + 2*mu/sigma^2, -z];
 int = Integrate[eq, {z, 0.001, 2*S0/(K*sigma^2)}, 
GenerateConditions -> False]*(2*
 S0/sigma^2)*(Gamma[nu + 2*mu/sigma^2]/Gamma[2*nu + 2*mu/sigma^2]);
int2[alpha_] := 
        int /. nu -> (-vu/2 + Sqrt[vu^2 + 8*alpha/sigma^2]/2) /. 
        vu -> (2*mu/sigma^2 - 1);

 F[alpha_] := F[alpha] = int2[alpha]/alpha;
 GWR[F, 1]
 TimeUsed[] (*Time used to compute the value*)
```

> `13.4836`
>   `2.184`

Before I ask my question, I would like to make a remark that 
the routine: **`GWR[]` has been tested with different functions and it gives correct answers up to 15 decimal places for those tested functions**. It gives me the answers in less than a minute.

However, when I tested with `F[]`, it gives me a wrong answer:

- when `K=95`, it gives me `13.4836`. The *correct anwer* is `15.643`.
- when `K=105`, it gives me `7.94016`. The *correct answer* is : `3.560`

It gives me the answers in less than 1 minute.

**So here is my question:**

Is there any thing which is bad for the function `F[alpha_]` that I don't know? If there is such a bad singulariy, how to remove it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Comment: Dear m_goldberg : could you please not vote to close it ? it is an important problem for me. And it is very interesting since it is used to compute the Asian option in a new way !

Comment: @m_goldberg -- I think the question has merit.  Wouldn't the OP and this site better benefit from improving the question rather then closing it.  The OP has done a lot of work, trying to solve his problem.  That alone merits praise.  As it stands the question seems focused on the problem of translating the computation into code.  I recommend the poster analyze the code and step through the calculations to identify the specific part of his code where the calculation goes wrong.  This may point him to a Mma problem or a translation problem.

Comment: @DuyNguyen -- Focus in on the problem and revise the question when you learn a bit more.  That will get you the most help from this forum.  Good luck with this, you have an interesting question.

Comment: Dear Jagra : Thank you for your encouragement ! I will when I learn more about it.

Comment: @DuyNguyen -- Note how I formatted the functions and output you describe in the last section of your post so that it becomes clearer.  It now better shows what comes from theory and what you've done in Mathematica.  Even this little bit of formatting can help the participants in the forum, focus better on the parts of the problem where in they can best help.

Comment: Thank so much Jagra !

Comment: My suggestion would be to select specific (rational) values for parameters to the greatest extent possible, substitute them in an pose the question here for that specific case.  How do you know the other values are correct?

Comment: Dear george2079: Asian options are available in the literature. I compare the results with those obtained by Monte Carlo and PDE methods.

Comment: ...so the error here might lie in your "new method" and have nothing to do with your mathematica implementation.

Comment: george2079: I know what you are saying, but we have the check the theoritical part carefully. Two of us checked it more than 10 times, we are 100% sure that the theoritical part is correct. The things that worry me is: I don't know much about the Hypergeometric1F1 function,, it might have some singularities that I am not aware of .

Comment: @ Dear Duy Nguyen. Yours answer  are  they correct? Increase the precision and compare with previous results.We'll see what happens.

Comment: I_Mariusz : I have increased the pricision but still not get to correct answers. I bet the bad things are at the singularities of Hypergeometric1F1. But I don't know to deal with it yet .

Comment: Maybe This be better: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.2505.pdf

Comment: @Duy Nguyen: why don't you do the z-intergral as I have shown before? It might simplify things.

Comment: Dr. Hintze: I did apply z-intergral you suggested. Did I miss any thing here ?

Comment: "The correct answer" - how are you getting the correct answers? Why not use that method instead?

Comment: "the singularities of Hypergeometric1F1" - the Kummer function is holomorphic (no poles or branch cuts), so your bet is way off in this case.

Comment: J.M: Thank you for your  comments.  the correct answer comes from a PDE method and Monte Carlo method.  Yes, I am not sure about the 1F1 function, so thank you for letting me know that it is holomorphic function : ))